# How to plot a bar / column in case price % change, similarly how to do that for volume change, like a threshold

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I don't think this should be difficulty to code, but I cant figure it out.

I want to plot a bar / column whenever price reached a % change of 2, green in case its up and red in case its down.

I also would like to create a bar / column whenever volume has reached a threshold of 6 million.

Not sure if it can be done in the same script.

**For the 6 million volume threshold.**

```
study(title="plot volume treshold", overlay=false)
if (volume > 6000000)

plot(style = columns)
Not sure how to make it know in case its a red or green bar.
```

**For the 2% change threshold**

```
study(title="plot % threshold", overlay=false)
if (close-close[1]=2)

plot(style = columns)
color(close > 2 = green)
color(close < 2 = red)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `close-close[1]==2`, but this is what it is:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

bgcolor(close-close[1]==2 ? (close > 2 ? color.green: color.red):na)
plot(volume> 6000000 ? volume : na, style = plot.style_columns)
```